# How to create full page capture screen from onepage and horizontal scroll applications?

Tags: javascript, python, screenshot

How to create a screenshot of an application that has horizontal scroll or scrolling in the form of a slider?

I would like to take a full screenshot, not just the first screen. For example, from applications like below.

https://piscinasdecemento.com/
https://studiochevojon.com/

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a similar project with HTML 2 CANVAS. it's a powerful library for generating images or pdfs from webpages.  Good Enough you, don't need any backend to do this. Only Javascript is needed (add some JQuery if you want).

check it out here
[https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-screen-capture-libraries?orderBy=RECOMMENDED&)

You can also try out other Javascript Libraries similar to html2canvas

here https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-screen-capture-libraries?orderBy=RECOMMENDED&